# I do not understand how to apply the Intermediate Value Theorem. Could you help?

Tags: calculus

I have two equation/domain pairs,

$$
\ln(x)=x-\sqrt{x}, \quad x\in (2,3) 
$$
and 
$$
\sin(x)=x^2-x, \quad x\in (1,2). 
$$
 The instructions I have been given are "*use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that there is a root of the given equation in the specified interval*".  I have absolutely no idea how to do so, and what I have looked at/found via Google/even seen here has only left me more confused.  Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a continuous function attains a positive value at one point and a negative value at another point, then somewhere in between it attains the value zero. In your first example let $f(x) = \ln x - x + \sqrt x$. You can check that $f(2) \approx .107$ and $f(3) \approx -.169$, so somewhere in between $2$ and $3$ lies a number $x$ satisfying $f(x) = 0$, i.e. $\ln x = x - \sqrt x$.

Comment: Okay, now how do I do that without invoking calculators?  It is strongly my impression that we're supposed to not use them.

Comment: Why don't you ask your instructor?

Comment: I did, and apparently that's only on tests.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, define $$f(x)=\ln x -x +\sqrt x$$

Now find $f(2)$ and $f(3)$.

You are going to get one positive answer and one negative answer. Intermediate Value theorem tells you that there is a zero between these two values and that is the point where you have a solution for your first equation.

Use the same trick for the second one and you will get a solution for that one too.